# Listbox selection events not being fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm getting strange behaviour from WPF `ListBox`.

My `ListBox` is displaying an observable collection of Attributes, each attribute has a string property called factoryfriendlyname. The value of factory friendly name is always unique. When I click on an item in the list box, the selection changed event is fired, and the item in question is selected.

The problem is at the same time it will also select two or three other items with no apparent connection, and will then not fire selection changed for any further selections.

If I do make further selections, the items are highlighted as if they are being selected, but selected items changed is not fired again. Rather than selecting a new node, further selections are added onto existing ones, so every time I click, another item turns blue.

I really can understand what is going on with the `ListBox`.

Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ToolBoxItems}"
         Name="nodelist" Grid.Column="0"
         Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single"
         SelectionChanged="DoSelectionChanged"
         DisplayMemberPath="FactoryFriendlyName"/>
```

`DoSeletionChanged` simply loads the selected item. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the XAML.  Just to safe, will you please post your DoSelectionChanged code?

Comment: I think it is good that you show your viewmode(ToolBoxItems) code.

Comment: Also, can you post how `ToolBoxItems` is created? If the exact same item reference is added to the list multiple times, then setting one copy as Selected will make all copies of that item Selected since they point to the same item in memory